# Python iterator next method

Tags: python, iterator

The [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Now, given the following:

```
nums = [2, 3, 4]
it = iter(nums)
it.__next__() 
next(it)
```

what's the difference between the last two statements? Both of them return the next item in the iterator without changing the iterator object. I see that `.__next__()` can be used to create iterator objects. Is that the only difference?

Comment: `next(it)` is the explicit way to do it, not using the dunder method (`next(it)` is calling the `__next__` method of the `it` object internally), same way you would to `a+b` not `a.__add__(b)`

Comment: "without changing the iterator object" - not true.

Comment: `__next__` is part of the implementation of the `next` function. `next` is clearly the one you are supposed to use.

Comment: There are differences in terms of error handling. Let's say you have some variable X which, due to some coding error, is not an iterator. In the case of trying to directly access the dunder function you'll get AttributeError whilst if you call *next()* on it you'll get TypeError. Also, whilst very unlikely, using *next()* allows for the underlying implementation to change. Use *next()*

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode What I mean is that the identity of the object is preserved after the operations.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answers, I see clearer now ! But how could next() change the iterator ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`next()` is used to get the next item in the sequence or `StopIteration` exception if its at the end.

`next()` does this by calling the `__next__()` method which is defined in the class.

An example

```
class my_list():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        self.pointer = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self.pointer >= len(self.data):
            self.pointer = 0
            raise StopIteration # to stop the iteration
        item = self.data[self.pointer]
        self.pointer += 1
        return item
    
my_list_obj = my_list()
print(next(my_list_obj)) # use next() function to call __next__()
print(next(my_list_obj))
print(next(my_list_obj))
print(next(my_list_obj))
print(next(my_list_obj))
print(next(my_list_obj))
print(next(my_list_obj, "empty")) # to print default value at the end
```

Gives Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
empty
```

`.__next__` is defined by the user to return the next object

`next()` is a method wrapper for `.__next__`

Same as `+` operator calls the `__add__`

Comment: Anyways, all of these are not implemented correctly. And importantly`__next__` doesn't make an object iterable

Comment: You mean  `def __iter__()` is missing ?